# Choosing from a list of predefined variables for build pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating an Azure Pipeline that will have some complex variables, but all of the variable values are one of four possible values. Is it somehow possible to choose variable values from a list when running the pipeline, or would I need to create an extension to accomplish this?

Comment: Can I know the status of this issue before weekend? Does below work for you?

Comment: I think my question was unclear, I'm sorry. I wanted to be able to have presets for variables, like "Team 1", "Team 2", etc., and choose from that list of variables when the pipeline is run. I ended up using config files in the code that's being built, and you just specify the name of the config file.

Comment: Pity for I got misunderstand here. Could you share the solution here and accept it as  answer? I think others include me are willing to learn such method:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Sorry, was on vacation, just posted that answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible, so I used a workaround.

I included config files alongside the project named in the style `config-team1.json`, `config-team2.json`, etc. I created a variable that can be edited when the pipeline is run called `Config.Name` and defaulted it to `team1`. I then created a PowerShell task for the pipeline that checks for an appropriately-named config file and copies it to `config.json`. For example, if the variable `Config.Name` is set to `team84`, the script looks for `config-team84.json` and copies it to `config.json`.

Two other variables are also used, `Config.SourceDirectory` and `Config.DestinationDirectory`. These just specify where to look for the config file and where to copy it to.

```bsh
$SourceFile = "config-$env:CONFIG_NAME.json"
$SourcePath = "$env:CONFIG_SOURCEDIRECTORY\$SourceFile"
$DestinationPath = "$env:CONFIG_DESTINATIONDIRECTORY\config.json"

Write-Host "Verifying that config file $SourceFile exists"

$FileExists = Test-Path -Path $SourcePath -PathType leaf
if (!$FileExists) {
  throw "Config file does not exist at $SourcePath, cannot continue."
}

Write-Host "Copying config file"
Copy-Item "$SourcePath" -Destination "$DestinationPath"
```

This is the end of the Pipelines-specific step, the rest is just additional info for how I'm using this in the actual project.

---

The project being built is written in .NET Core, so I used [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/). An example config file is:

```js
{
  "someKey": "someValue",
  "anotherKey": 4,
  "yetAnotherKey": true
}
```

You can get the config data like this:

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("config.json", false) // false means the file is not optional
    .Build();
```

In the above, `configuration` will be of type [`IConfigurationRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

You can use this configuration object directly:

```cs
var someVal = configuration["someKey"];
```

Or you can create a strongly-typed class for the config if you put the keys inside a parent key:

```js
{
  "myConfig": {
    "someKey": "someValue",
    "anotherKey": 4,
    "yetAnotherKey": true
  }
}
```

The C# class will look like this:

```cs
public class TestConfiguration
{
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }
    public int AnotherKey { get; set; }
    public bool YetAnotherKey { get; set; }
}
```

Instantiate and use the class like this:

```cs
var testConfig = configuration.GetSection("myConfig").Get<TestConfiguration>();
var someVal = testConfig.SomeKey;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of powershell script to split the values firstly.

For example, there has a variable names `var`, and its value is `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`. And during the pipeline, I just want the value `one` be used.

**Step1:**

Write a `ps1` file which contain below script to split out those values.

```
Param(
[string]$a
)

[array]$b = $a.split('.')
[string]$ma = $b[0]
```

**Note:** I split the variable based on `.`. So I store values as `one.two.three.four`.

[image]

**Step2:**

Since the value should be split first before others, here add `Powershell` task in the top and configure as below format:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Step3:**

After we split it successfully, based on the scenario you want, this value should also be available for next tasks.

Just add another script in `split.ps1` file which **set the variable which store the value we want as output variable**.

[image]

Then configure the **reference name** in the `Powershell` task.

[image]

---

Now, all of the next tasks can call that value by using `$(ref.var)`.